# Is it possible to stream video from USB camera and Audio from Mobile microphone for RTMP streaming in android

Tags: android, rtmp, microphone

Currently Im able to stream to youtube using this library:

https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java using android mobile camera.

When I tried with USB camera attached mobile and I can achieve the same using this library:
https://github.com/pedroSG94/Stream-USB-test

What I need now is, to use mobile's microphone for audio and USB camera for video for the rtmp streaming to youtube. Please suggest me some solutions.

Comment: @Moahmed Ashik did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @JohnJones  Yes, The above the mentioned library itself working now.

Comment: @Moamed Ashik Would you see it if possible to kindly share the code with me? I have a thermal camera for android that I need to send to a raspberry. I tried the github above, but it's stuck in a black screen. Additionally the developer said he isn't interested in giving support to UVCcamera because he doesn't own one

Comment: @JohnJones  did you add this line in manifest 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>

Comment: Yes, i did. There is a github issue in regards to that. Unfortunately for me, clicking the stream button does nothing, no errors, nothing. the screen is black all the time

Comment: @JohnJones check this repo:  https://github.com/imashik/rtmp-streaming it may help

Comment: When i connect my USB camera, the app is not shown in the permission box to give permissions to: https://imgur.com/Pqq4X1m

Comment: @JohnJones Currently I dont have USB camera to check the code, I created the repo from old project which was tested and working, may be I missed something while recreating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying with headphone, same code is working now. Video is captured from USB camera and audio is captured from Headphone mic